# How to make INDEX(, MATCH()) faster?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

The figure below is self-explanatory:
 I'm looking up values in a long data table (raw_data!) using INDEX(, MATCH()) and I happen to have a CONCAT() function within the match() to construct the date I want to search.

At 15000 thousand rows, and the same structure in 4 sheets, this spreadsheet is taking ~40sec to calculate. How can I make this faster?

Here's the formula in text:

```
=INDEX(raw_data!$C:$C, MATCH(CONCAT($F3, DATE(G$1, MONTH($C3), DAY($C3))), raw_data!$M:$M))
```

[image]

Comment: taking DATE() and CONCAT() out of there will probably help, but I'm looking for a way to make match and index work faster

Comment: @Scott done. Added formulas as text

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that a. your rawdata is sorted on col M and b. you don't need an exact match?

Comment: @jkpieterse You're correct. My raw_data!M:M is  key column. I built it concatenating 'AMU&Date' (AMU is the code for the location).
I should probably use a MATCH(,,0) for exact match in this formula, right?

Comment: It looks like you are just doing a lot of calculations which depending on your computer setup will take time. The Index/Match is probably the quickest method.  It takes time to do the number of calculations you are doing.  Also check for volatile functions in other parts of the workbook as these will also calculate every time.  change you calculations to manual to only do it when you want.

Comment: @Scott, would it help to use array formulas {INDEX(, MATCH)} to make it faster? I'm convinced that DATE() and CONCAT() within the formulas are slowing things down and will upgrade that part

Comment: NO!!! array formulas will make it slower.

Comment: @ScottCraner OK! Won't do :)

Comment: jkpieterse asked the crucial question. Is the raw_data!M:M column SORTED? If not, then you can massively improve performance if you keep the raw_data sorted by that column M..

Comment: @MacroMarc -- Excellent, it's sorted now. Slight improvement, down to ~30sec. Thank you

Comment: is the formula correct though? You need to make sure the returned value is the same as the one searched for using binary search.

Comment: @MacroMark mentions an important point, people tend to forget to mention that the matched range has to contain the sought after value otherwise it'll return the next smaller (or larger) one. That's IME usually the reason why people always use a linear search, not because their data isn't sorted.

Comment: Precisely why I asked the question; to trigger some thought :-)

Comment: @Robin And.... I had 29/Feb (leap years) wrong in my binary search! I will switch to a linear MATCH(,,0).

The spreadsheet is now VERY slow, seems like I will have to break it up in parts, or starting using R for this data munging step.

Comment: @jkpieterse As I pointed above, you were very well correct: I had wrong results being returned when using that type of search. The slowness is worse now, and I am researching alternatives.

Comment: Make sure your column M is sorted and try this version of the MATCH part:
IF(MATCH(CONCAT($F3, DATE(G$1, MONTH($C3), DAY($C3))), raw_data!$M:$M,1)=$F3,MATCH(CONCAT($F3, DATE(G$1, MONTH($C3), DAY($C3))), raw_data!$M:$M,1),NA())

Comment: Hey @jkpieterse, getting back to this one: what's the rationale behind the above? I can't get it to work: this construction will always return me NA , do you agree?  I think MATCH()=F3 will always evaluate FALSE.

Comment: The formula is wrong I see now, this is the correct one: IF(INDEX(raw_data!$M:$M,MATCH(CONCAT($F3, DATE(G$1, MONTH($C3), DAY($C3))), raw_data!$M:$M,1))=CONCAT($F3, DATE(G$1, MONTH($C3), DAY($C3))),MATCH(CONCAT($F3, DATE(G$1, MONTH($C3), DAY($C3))), raw_data!$M:$M,1),NA()) The idea behind it is that MATCH(a,b,1) does a binary search (google for it) which is lots and lots faster than the MATCH(a,b,0) variant but may return non-exact matches, hence the test for a match first. Clear as mud? :-)